# up to 20% Numerical error or Bug in ten line code block

Tags: c++, c, numerical-methods, rounding-error

Rewriting a single tiny block of code of an application has yielded a considerable performance improvement. The code is 100% sequential, thus there should be no hidden perturbations to the values stored in memory.

Double-checking that the results after computation are the same has shown an up-to 20% relative error in the results, so the question is if this can be explained by numerical error in the algorithm or there is an error in the algorithm itself and the two blocks are not equivalent.

Conceptually, the main modification has been replacing this

```
for m=0,...
  result += gradient * temp[m]
```

with this

```
for m=0,...
  sum_temp += temp[m]
result = gradient * sum_temp
```

While in the process dealing with the process of defining new arrays and initializing them.

EDIT: (for clarity) so-called 'result' in the code below are `SoGrSca` and `SoGrSca`'s elements

EDIT: typical values for (final) result are +-1e-8

Actual code is as follows (C++, weird-named nested arrays have been kept untouched at the expense of clarity)

```
// Three relevant macros for tidyness
//
#define FOR_I3 for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
#define LOOP_n_N(NUM)  for (int n = 0; n < NUM; n++)
#define LOOP_m_N(NUM)  for (int m = 0; m < NUM; m++)

// Toy definitions for eye-friendlyness
// on Stackoverflow
//
const int NDIM = 6; 
const int ORDER = 20;

// More definitions...
//
// 1) Arrays of doubles
//
// SoGrSca, SoGrVec, PrimSca, Jaco_Sol, PrimVec, mat_der_sol
//
// 2) Arrays of integers
//
// mat_co1, mat_co2



// Version 1 of the code
//
FOR_I3 SoGrSca[0][nk + l][i]           = 0.0;
FOR_I3 FOR_J3 SoGrVec[0][nk + l][j][i] = 0.0;
//
LOOP_n_N(NDIM) LOOP_m_N(ORDER) {

  int idof1 = ORDER*mat_co1[NDIM*l + n] + m;
  int idof2 = mat_Gr[ndof*n +   ORDER*mat_co2[NDIM*l + n] + m           ];

  double grp_temp = mat_der_sol[idof1]*GsGm1*PrimSca[1][nk + idof2]/PrimSca[0][nk + idof2];
  FOR_I3 SoGrSca[0][nk + l][i]      += Jaco_Sol[nk + l][n][i]*grp_temp;
  FOR_J3 {
    double grp_temp = mat_der_sol[idof1]*PrimVec[0][nk + idof2][j];
    FOR_I3 SoGrVec[0][nk + l][j][i] += Jaco_Sol[nk + l][n][i]*grp_temp;
  }
}

// Store SoGrSca and SoGrVec values ...

// Version 2 of the code
//
FOR_I3 SoGrSca[0][nk + l][i]           = 0.0;
FOR_I3 FOR_J3 SoGrVec[0][nk + l][j][i] = 0.0;
//
double grp_temp_A_v[NDIM];
double grp_temp_B_v[NDIM][3];
LOOP_n_N(NDIM){                    
        grp_temp_A_v[n] = 0.0;                  
        FOR_I3  grp_temp_B_v[n][i] = 0.0;       
}
LOOP_n_N(NDIM) LOOP_m_N(ORDER) {
  int idof1 = ORDER * mat_co1[NDIM*l + n] + m;
  int idof2 = mat_Gr[ndof*n +   ORDER*mat_co2[NDIM*l + n] + m           ];
  grp_temp_A_v[n] += mat_der_sol[idof1] * GsGm1*PrimSca[1][nk + idof2]/PrimSca[0][nk + idof2];
  FOR_J3 grp_temp_B_v[n][j] += mat_der_sol[idof1] * PrimVec[0][nk + idof2][j];
}

LOOP_n_N(NDIM) {
  FOR_I3 SoGrSca[0][nk + l][i]      += Jaco_Sol[nk + l][n][i] * grp_temp_A_v[n];
  FOR_J3 {
    FOR_I3 SoGrVec[0][nk + l][j][i] += Jaco_Sol[nk + l][n][i] * grp_temp_B_v[n][j];
  }
}


// Compare SoGrSca and SoGrVec... 
//
// ERROR: they are different
```

Comparing algorithm is, given `y_old` and `y_new`,

```
( abs( y_old - y_new ) / ( abs(y_old) + z ) ) < epsilon // 'true' means equality
```

where z protects against zero division errors,

`z=1e-10`

and epsilon required to pass is huge, i.e. `epsilon=0.2`
While it should be closer to e.g. `1e-7`

FUN EDIT: just another example of joining a project with already-well-established macros lol

Comment: You know, you make the code unreadable by using macros to make it look like a different language.

Comment: i guess the original version was `result += gradient * temp[m]`

Comment: Please create a [mcve], the code posted is simply not readable.

Comment: Reading this code is absolutely painful. Can't you simplify ?

Comment: If you really want to use a macro, use `#define REP(v,n) for(int v = 0; v < (n); ++v)` and use it simulate all others. E.g. `FOR_I3` -> `REP(i, 3)`

Comment: The "actual code" does not contain any `result` nor `sum_temp`. How is that related to your modified code lines?

Comment: Your substitution is valid as long as `gradient` remains constant across the iterations.

Comment: Get rid of the secret macro language and re-post the code. Code obfuscation is off-topic here, this isn't one of the puzzle sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating point number arithmetic is not [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property). That means there are cases where the following statement is true

```
x * (a + b) != x * a + x * b;
```

If you move the multiplication out of your loop and expect the exact same result, you assume that the distributive law is always true, which it is not.
As an example I came up with [this godbolt snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/ac6EjhWMe).

Comment: Are you sure that this explains the 20% discrepancy ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust I could get a 1.3% discrepancy with just two numbers. If you add a lot of those numbers, the discrepancy will get worse like e.g. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/6aMMhEW89)

Comment: Note that we don't even know the starting values, though.

Comment: Of course, but are there even subtractions in this code ?

Comment: For that to not happen, one must carefully choose a numerically stable method (even for simple things like addition and multiplication)

Comment: Your diagnostic seems premature.

Comment: @YvesDaoust A subtraction can just be the addition of a negative number... Tho OP did not provide the actual numbers that were added, so there might be negatives in there.

Comment: That's what I mean. You have no idea if there are cancellations or not.

Comment: Well, if `temp` stands for "temperature"... I'd hope they are using Kelvin (or Rankine).